# Function or var not defined .js

Tags: javascript, rgba

I have a problem with the code below. I seem to be getting either var not defined or function not defined depending on where I place the brace (obviously). What I'm trying to accomplish is to convert an array into a string, in order to see what kind of data I have and how I should go about displaying it (histogram or something). This is the code:

```
function drawImage(imageObj) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageX = 10;
  var imageY = 10;
  var imageWidth = imageObj.width;
  var imageHeight = imageObj.height;

  context.drawImage(imageObj, imageX, imageY);

  var imageData = context.getImageData(imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);
  var data = imageData.data;

  for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    var red = data[i];
    var green = data[i + 1];
    var blue = data[i + 2];
    var alpha = data[i + 3];
  }
} //the brace that causes problems

function myFunction() {
  red.toString();
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = red;
}
// alternative position of brace?

var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
  drawImage(this);
};

imageObj.src = 'myimg.jpg';
```

Can somebody see where I have gone wrong with this?

Comment: You're not calling `myFunction` anywhere, but even if you did it wouldn't have access to `red` which is scoped locally to the previous function.

Comment: `red.toString();` as a statement won't do anything.

Comment: why you have myFunction ? You can not use red inside your myFunction. javascript has functional scope for variables.

Comment: @Andy I'm actually calling (left that part out of the code) it, but like you say it doesn't access var red.

Comment: Previous comments, plus: drawImage(this) could be drawImage(imageObj) instead.  I'm not sure what 'this' would be in your onload callback.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has functional scope you can find more details here - [variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

By changing position of braces you are actually changing scope for `myFunction` function. When you will move curly braces after `myFunction` then it will become inner function for `drawImage` and get access to variable `red`.

Comment: Javascript has block scoping as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far, especialy @Anshul. If I use var data I get all the RGBA values for my image, but only one value for var red. It seems that the for loop doesn't do what it's supposed to. I use a 20 x 20 px image so I should have 400 values for red, since var data has 1600 right?